Is there any way to play Spotify API or SoundCloud API music (track) in your own media player?
I am trying to make an application where I am supposed to call an intent to Spotify or SoundCloud Android API and get their music track (public one) playing in my own media player (I have already made my own media player which have all functionalities), is there any way to do so?
Also, whenever the intent is called, it is supposed to play some random music track not from any particular playlist.
So, if there is any alternate way or free api to get these functionalities, please tell me.
On SoundCloud, although there seems this type of functionality, but it is always showing that I can't register my application, so not able to use that either.
On Spotify, there doesn't seem any such functionality.

I do not think it is possible on Spotify. If you want to use their SDK then you can play it via the Spotify app. If you want to use your own player you can play the 30s preview and not the entire song. SoundCloud on the other hand is not accepting new applications as you mentioned. You can check out my library which is a Kotlin wrapper around the Spotify Web API if you want to build your own music app!
https://github.com/rubenquadros/KoVibes

Thank you very much for your github, I will surely look into it. Really appreciate the efforts.

Via the API you can call the /tracks/{track_id}/streams endpoint in order to get MP3 and HLS urls
